# JMenu fonts on some Windows machines strangely boldfaced

Tags: java, swing

Using recent 8.x JREs on some Windows 7 Pro systems, we're seeing some odd font behavior and don't know where it's coming from.

This particular standalone (not an applet, not inside a browser or other "framework") application doesn't do much with look-and-feel settings, other than retrieving `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`, logging it, and calling `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(that_retrieved_name)`.  The goal was to have the application behave more or less like a native app, rather than forcing it to try and appear identical everywhere.

What we didn't expect was so much variability between Microsoft Windows systems.  From the logging mentioned above, we know that the L&F in question is the standard `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`, and we know that if the system property `swing.useSystemFontSettings` is true (the default), then WindowsLookAndFeel is supposed to retrieve local font settings from magic la-la-land and use them in preference to the builtin L&F fonts.  Something in that process is going weird.

The code in question is using standard components (`new JFrame()`, `new JMenuBar()`, a few `new JMenu("foo")`), I'll try to post an snippet later.  Here's what the mockup looks like on most Windows systems:

[image: title and menu identical font]

The title font and menu font are identical.  And if we retrieve the two Font objects, they both report the same metrics ("Segoe UI", isBold = false).  Okay, fine.

Copying the built application to another Windows box, it suddenly looks like this:

[image: menu randomly boldfaced]

Now the menu font is heavier, darker, boldface compared to the title.  Querying the two Fonts, both claim to be identical Segoe plain fonts, but they're visibly different.  (The difference is more obvious when menus are showing and every entry is the same.)  The second Windows box has no custom fonts installed, no strange tweaks done to the desktop settings.

So, it would seem that in WindowsLookAndFeel initialization, whatever is represented by the key "`win.menu.font`" is replacing the default.  (That property doesn't exist, but it's how la-la-land lookups are written.)  Except that if that were the case, then querying the UIManager's `Menu.font` or calling getFont() on a menu instance would return the changed Font object.  And we're getting the exact same Font object back for the menus as for the title.

Where *else* do we need to be looking to find the source of the difference?  We don't necessarily want to "fix" it, but we do need to be able to tell users "if you see this, or if you *want* this, then you need to change such-and-such on your Windows system".

Comment: It appears the title bar font is doing the opposite:  bolder in the first screen shot, lighter in the second one.  The fact that the window title font is not under Java’s control suggests that you have done nothing wrong and it’s normal to see what you’re seeing.  I don’t why they’re different, though.

Comment: @VGR I wish I could get a screenshot of one of the popup dialogs from the second computer, where *everything* is boldface, it might be more obvious then.  (I'll mock up an example as soon as I have time.)  It's kind of ugly and may need "fixing" after all, despite what I originally wrote.